# Color in Bash Prompt messing up the prompt

Tags: bash, shell

In my bashrc file I have my prompt set as follows:

```
  TC_GRE="^[[0;32;40m"                                                          
  TC_RESET="^[[0m"                                                              
  PS1="${TC_GRE}i:${TC_RESET}"
```

The prompt therefore is simply a green "i:". When I work in my shell and I scroll up in the history my command line messes up. Consider the following:

```
i: shell_command_one
i: shell_command_two
i: shell_command_three
```

Now when I go up in my history the line might look something like this:

```
i: shell_comshell_command_two
```

If I hit enter on that it executes shell_command_two. (Notice how the shell_com is just junk characters on the terminal.

I suspect it might have something to do with the color characters being non-printing. Does anyone know how to fix this in bash?

p.s. I'm not sure if this is better posted on superuser but I thought it might be best here since its about bash scripting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you have a malformed CSI [color code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).  Try this in your `.bashrc` file:

```
TC_GRE="\[\033[0;32m\]"                                                          
PS1="${TC_GRE}i: "
```

Comment: Worked with a small fix...

TC_GRE="\[\033[0;32;40m\]"
TC_RESET="\[\033[0;0m\]"
PS1="${TC_GRE}i:${TC_RESET}"

I still wanted to reset the foreground color so it wasn't always green. Thanks!

Comment: It's not so much a malformed color code, as you were inserting characters into the prompt which did not move the cursor when printed. The `\[...\]` pair wraps those characters so that `bash` doesn't get confused about how much space on-screen the prompt occupies.

Comment: One step towards understanding how these colour codes work. It is helpful to break them down....